# Is there a way to ask IntelliJ IDEA to skip indexing some specific jar files added as library?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, indexing

Our project (managed by Maven) has a jar dependency which contains lots and lots of .js files. The problem is that we modify this dependency very often, and every time we `mvn install` it, IntelliJ IDEA will start to re-index all those .js files, and then becomes very slow or even dead.

So I wonder is there a way to ask IntelliJ to skip indexing a specific jar library?

Comment: [There is IntelliJ IDEA configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88958#comment=27-598170) for excluding library roots. Note that it may not work with Maven projects since the settings you make to the library will be discarded on the next project reimport.